# Ruby rspec command not working could it be because Ubuntu 12 is 64 bit?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rspec, 64-bit

I've had lots of headaches on this issue. I'm currently working on an assignment that requires me to use rspec on ruby. Whenever I run the rspec command I keep getting errors like

home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/core/configuration.rb:780:in 'load': cannot load such file
fro, home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in 'map'....

They're just endless and confusing. I figure I wasn't doing something right in my .rb files no matter how I tweak according to the test rules same issue. I figured I'd start from scratch with a basic rspec tutorial example, still getting the same errors. I felt it might be my ruby installation so I uninstalled and this time I installed using RVM - still the same errors I get. No matter what I try - simple test codes (assuming maybe my assignment one is buggy), I've tried rspec, rspec spec, rake spec, still the same results.

I'm really confused. I'm new to ruby and my assignment is due in a few days. I have an idea how to write the code I need to get the required results but I have been restricted to use rspec which is really annoying. Then I remembered once when I tried to install LAMPP with my 64 bit Ubunutu and I was told I need to get 32 bit libraries or something, which I did and LAMPP now works (I can't use myphp admin though). So I'm thinking, could it be that I need to get a 32 bit version of Ubuntu 12 instead? Does it have anything to do with my rspec problem or I'm just doing something else wrong?

Oh and yes, I have ruby gems installed. Your answers would be really appreciated guys.

Comment: Please post the exact error message and the exact code you are using.

Comment: What happen when you launch irb ?

Comment: Hi I already pasted the error messages I get. It's quite so many lines of code and I can't copy and paste all from the terminal

Comment: I meant I can only type what i see. I'm unable to copy and paste from terminal

Comment: irb is the Ruby interactive interpreter. It should be located at the same place as the interpreter. Oh, and try to run a simple test test, so you will know if the problem is caused by your ruby setup or your code.

Comment: Oh thanks I know what irb is. Yes I did run very simple tests but I still get the same results

Answer (score 0):

1.) delete your *Gemfile.lock* file

2.) run `bundle install` if you want to exclude anything use the --without flag ex: `bundle install --without production`

3.) run `bundle exec rspec spec/`

This should make it work now. Let me know.