# uninitialized constant when migrating rails from ubuntu to osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, devise

i'm trying to move my rails app from ubuntu to osx. when running rspec, i get the following obscure error:

```
/Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/support/devise.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant RequestHelpers (NameError)
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core.rb:92:in `configure'
    from /Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/support/devise.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `each'
    from /Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/spec_helper.rb:21:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/josh/dev/myproject/spec/controllers/comments_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
    from /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@myproject/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

everything works nicely in Ubuntu, so i guess it must be environmental. Any ideas where to start digging?

thanks
- Josh

EDIT: no idea why, but the file request_helpers.rb could not be found by rake. moving it elsewhere resolved the issue.

Comment: Have you migrated your database to fit the current scheme?

Comment: Try my other suggestion here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13302121/1343134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hardly seems an operating system problem, much rather a matter of configuration. Make sure your environemnt is the same in terms of:

- using rvm installed the same way
- having all the needed gems in the Gemfile
- using bundle to execute rspec
- using the same version of everything.

By te way this is not an obscure message, it's in fact pretty clear:

> `uninitialized constant RequestHelpers (NameError)`

so the `spec/support/devise.rb` file can't find the needed class.

Have you written that file? If not, how did you generate it? Repeat the procedure to generate it (probably `rake something` or `rails generate something`) and it will be OK.